# Other People can't Connect to My Server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have Windows 8 and I have the official version of minecraft. I recently made a Minecraft server and port forwarded it using Hamachi. It worked fine, but I wanted to port forward it without Hamachi, using my router's website I am aware of how port forwarding is done, the method works for other people. However. I found my ip4 adress in the cmd wingow by tiping "ipconfig", and tiped this ip into my servers properties. I used this to join my server and it worked, however my friends can't connect to it.

Comment: Please don't make your question an entirely different question.  If you have a new question, feel free to ask a new one, but using your old question to ask a new one isn't how to do it.

Comment: The previous question was too similar to other posts on this website, as I discovered and the solution was very clear, answered by other posts in just as much (if not more) detail. I know It's not the best way but I don't have another email adress that I could use. Sorry.

Comment: It doesn't matter.  That's what you asked, and someone answered.  You're not allowed to change what the question has asked after that, beyond additional clarification and editing.  Edits are **not** for asking a completely different question.

Comment: My reputation was not enough for asking a new question. I know, the reason for that is my previous questions' lack of detail and it's my fault for getting bat reputation on the site. If you have any other ideas to gett a better "score", I will try it.

Comment: That's the system working as designed; you've had a bad track record with your contributions, so the system isn't letting you ask new ones.  That means you have to improve your existing ones so that they are better.  Editing a question to ask comething totally different is exactly one of those things that doesn't help.

Comment: Ok I'll try making the original question better. But you've got to admit that the question is too similar to other ones but... I wil try.

Answer (score 1):

So the 192.168.x.xxx address is your local address, so only people that are connected to your network can join. You need to use your external IP. This can be found by [asking Google What's my IP](https://www.google.com/search?q=what%27s%20my%20ip). Put the IP that comes up in your properties file and give that address to everybody, and then it should work!

Actually, leave the Server IP blank in your properties and then you should be able to join through your external IP!

Comment: Sorry, even I can't acces the server like this

Comment: Why can't you access the server?

Comment: @PixelClips try leaving server-ip blank and connect to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` yourself.